# checkboxList use arrayHalper and get values yii2

Tags: html, checkbox, yii2

This is my form checkboxList with arrayhalper:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'reg_id')->checkboxList(
        arrayHelper::Map(Riders::find()->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id])->all(),'rider_id',
            function($model) { return **$model->rider_firstname . " (" . $model->cagoriesCategory->category_name . ")"**; }),
        ['class' => 'checkbox-inline', 'id' => 'person' ]), ?>
</div>
```

The label its work correctly, example: `Jilly (MasterA)`. But I want to get value difference with label, example like this `Jilly:MasterA`. How to give values like this?

Comment: I don't understand what do you need. Please explain better ...

Comment: Sorry for bad language. simple example like this `<input type="checkbox" id="person" value="Ristha:MasterA">Ristha (MasterA)</input>` @scaisEdge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its work what i want, thank to @GAMITG

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'reg_id')->checkboxList( 
    arrayHelper::Map(Riders::find()->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id])->all(), function($model) { return $model->rider_firstname . ":" . $model->cagoriesCategory->category_name; }, 
        function($model) { return $model->rider_firstname . " (" . $model->cagoriesCategory->category_name . ")"; }), 
    ['item' => function($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) { 
        $return = '<label>'; 
        $return .= '<input type="checkbox" name="' . $name . '" value="' . $value . '" class="checkbox-inline" id="person1">';
        $return .= '<span>' . ucwords($label) . '</span>'; 
        $return .= '</label>'; 
        return $return; 
    } ]); ?>
</div>
```

then javascript code to cek it:

```
$('[id="person1"]:checked').each(function() {
    var arr = $(this).val();
    alert(arr);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change array value syntax. like as,

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'reg_id')->checkboxList(
        arrayHelper::Map(Riders::find()->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id])->all(), function($model) { return $model->rider_firstname . " : " . $model->cagoriesCategory->category_name; },
            function($model) { return $model->rider_firstname . " (" . $model->cagoriesCategory->category_name . ")"; }),
        ['class' => 'checkbox-inline', 'id' => 'checkbox' ]); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: thank, i want get value like this because can make me easily get split to show on table

Comment: sorry, When i use simple example in above its work correctly when i show use alert `$('#idOfButton').click(function(){ $('[id="person"]:checked').each(function(){ var arr = $(this).val(); alert(arr); }); });` but when i use arrayhelper like that its not work. @GAMITG

Comment: Above example works fine with `arrayHelper` on my localhost.

Comment: its not shown my alert when i use `arrayHelper` T.T @GAMITG

Comment: I will check than say you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94469/discussion-between-stfvns-and-gamitg).